# Jsoup. Удаление дочернего элемента

Tags: java, android, jsoup, парсер

Имеется такой код

```
<div class="line">
  <nobr> 10.0 </nobr>
  <nobr> 11.0 </nobr>
  <div id="r1234">
    <nobr> 11.0 </nobr>
</div>
```

Мне нужно вытащить всю информацию с div line, кроме той, которая находится в r1234. Что я уже только не пробовал, не помогает. И String.replace что-то работать не хочет и выводит все равно всю инфу. Буду рад за любой совет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Просто найдите нужный элемент и удалите его методом `remove`

```
Element divLine = ...;
divLine.getElementById("r1234").remove();
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Отметить как правильный ответ смогу лишь через 7 минут :)